# Copy rpm install then delete rpm in one step

Tags: docker, rpm

I'm trying to keep a docker image as small as possible so I want to copy an RPM, which is not available from a URL, install it then delete it before the commit. Therefore the source rpm never gets committed

Is the only way to do this by serving the rpm from a web server and doing the whole thing as a

```
curl http://myserver/myrpm && rpm myrpm && rm myrpm
```

Or is there a better way? - I know there are option to these commands

At the moment I am doing this in separate steps but that results in lots of layers to the image

Comment: You could simplify the above to `rpm -ivh http://myserver/myrpm`.

Comment: Yes but I don't currently have the rpm on a server, only in the directory I'm building the container in

Comment: I did put the files on a web server and did the above in the end!